# My testfor scoreboard command is not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

`testfor @p {score_money_min:5}` is not working for me. The output, without the time and date, says *Earthtomars did not match the required data structure*, but I have 1000 points / credits.

Edit: is there a way to make it work of Minecraft bedrock?

Comment: Remember: A close vote is not a super downvote; it may be a badly written question, but it's still a valid question.

Comment: @aytimothy true, but I would argue most people have no idea what this question is asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that

```
/testfor @p {score_money_min:5}
```

doesn't work because of two reasons. Firstly you have to use square brackets and join the selector and data tag. Like so:

```
/testfor @p[score_money_min:5]
```

then the last problem is that you have to use '=' in selectors and not ':'.

```
/testfor @p[score_money_min=5]
```

Hope I helped!